Changing SENTRY_EVENT_RETENTION_DAYS value in .env
I have a self-hosted sentry running for about 40 days. I want to change
settings for SENTRY_EVENT_RETENTION_DAYS from 90 days to 30 days in .env file. What steps do I need to take for the changes to take effect? I don't want to lose all data. I use the docker compose solution.
I tried restarting the docker containers, but I think it will be necessary to create them anew. I am afraid of losing all existing data
